# Error when using play on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script running `play` and the following error appears "randomly" on my terminal:

`play WARN alsa: under-run`

What is causing it? If there's no obvious solution, can I hide it somehow?

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

$(stat -c %y ~/custom/log.txt > ~/custom/update.txt)

while :
do
    now=$(stat -c %y ~/custom/log.txt)
    update=$(cat ~/custom/update.txt)
    if [ "$now" != "$update" ]
    then
        $(stat -c %y ~/custom/log.txt > ~/custom/update.txt)
        $(play --single-threaded -nq synth 0.025 saw 299 vol 0.025)
    fi
done
```

Comment: Just a note, but you don't need to surround the `stat` and `play` lines with `$(...)` for the first `stat` command, or in your `if` block. `$(...)` is for capturing the output from commands, and since you're not assigning this output to any variables, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the error, you can simply divert `stderr` to `/dev/null`:

```
play --single-threaded -nq synth 0.025 saw 299 vol 0.025 2>/dev/null
```

Note that this will also divert any other errors to `/dev/null` as well.